# Ruby reverse iterate array but not index

Tags: python, arrays, ruby, loops

How to convert this code to Ruby involving reversed array iteration and but not indexing?

```
    out = 0
    for index,x in enumerate(reversed(d)):
        out += x*pow(2,index)
```

From what I can understand from the Python code, the array `d` is reversed but the index of the elements are not?
*Twisting!*
How to do this in Ruby?

Comment: *"the array d is reversed but the index of the elements are not"* - what?

Comment: Yeah! Check a code here  - http://galvanist.com/post/53478841501/python-reverse-enumerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the next output in Python:

```
for index, string in enumerate(reversed(['zero', 'one', 'two'])):
    print index, string
# 0 two
# 1 one
# 2 zero
```

Then you can use `reverse` before applying the enumerator, in this case `each`, so, it'll take your array as `['two', 'one', 'zero']`, and the index for each iteration will remain intact:

```
['zero', 'one', 'two'].reverse.each_with_index do |word, index|
  puts "#{index} #{word}"
end
# 0 two
# 1 one
# 2 zero
```

Comment: It would be slightly more performant (I think?... Haven't benchmarked it) to use `[...].reverse_each.with_index`.

Comment: The `reverse_each` [seems](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/d84272d49b2462db862f4efeea809ae7) to be slightly slower.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of your Python code snippet in Ruby is:

```
d.reverse_each.with_index.inject(0) do |out, (x,i)|
  out += x * 2**i
end
```